# Issues with htaccess url rewriting, cannot rewrite any url but www to non-www works fine

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've had trouble with this the last couple of days, looking up tutorials and other peoples examples (including a lot from this site) but I just cannot get it to work.

currently my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^forside/([0-9]+)$ index.php?main=forside
```

I need to change domain.dk/index.php?main=forside 
to domain.dk/forside.

and domain.dk/index.php?main=article&id=10
to domain.dk/article/10

I've looked in my phpinfo() and cannot seem to find any information on if the server supports mod_rewrite or not, but the www to non-www redirect works perfectly, so that's where I'm kinda lost.

If anyone has an idea on what is going wrong or how I could fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you set RewriteRuleLogLevel 3 (or more), and let us know what the RewriteLog says?

Comment: I tried adding 
RewriteLogLevel 9 RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
but i get an internal server error, I'm sorry I haven't messed a lot with htaccess so I don't even know what it does, but to be clear, I don't have access to the server configurations, as it's not hosted locally nor on my own server.

Comment: Have you searched for mod_rewrite in your phpinfo() output?  I have mine there :)

Comment: @dezso
yes I have, I cannot find it at all there - weird part is, my www to non-www clearly works.

Comment: Do you have a row like this (without a beginning #):
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
in your httpd.conf?

Comment: Sorry to be a pestilence, but where exactly is httpd.conf placed? I only have access to the root of my webserver, where i have the standard public_html, public_ftp etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different patterns for *forside* and *articles*, so you should have two different rules.

```
RewriteRule ^forside$ index.php?main=forside
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ index.php?main=article&id=$1
```

If you want to condense them to one, you could use the following (untested). However, this is not as strict as the above.

```
RewriteRule ^(forside|article)(:?/|/([0-9]+))$ index.php?main=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: No luck on those rules :/ Placed them after my www redirect.

Comment: I got it working using your code, I must've been a noob or something, thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries. Yes, for clarity, those rules should go after your www redirect.